# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Unable to delete in PHP & Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

My delete function has some problems.. it is a bug maybe, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

I am trying to delete from three different tables when I delete a WHOLE Audit Form. I understand that you must delete the one with foreign keys first. But there are chances that there is no data in the Audit_Trans_Photo

audit_trans_photoDAO

```
public function removeAuditID($auditID) {
        $sql = 'delete ignore from audit_trans_photo where auditID=:auditID';
```

audit_transactionDAO

```
public function remove($auditID) {
        $sql = 'delete from audit_transaction where auditID=:auditID';
```

audit_form

```
public function remove($auditID) {
        $sql = 'delete from audit_form where auditID=:auditID';
```

delete page

```
$passed_array = unserialize($_POST['input_name']);

foreach ($passed_array as $id){
    $dao3 = new Audit_Trans_PhotoDAO();
    $dao3->removeAuditID($id);

    $dao = new Audit_TransactionDAO();
    $dao->remove($id);

    $dao2 = new Audit_FormDAO();
    $dao2->remove($id);
}
```

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Comment: If you set your FK constraint as ON DELETE CASCADE, you only have to delete the parent table, it will auto delete the rows in the child table

Comment: I doubt(but don't know for sure) that mysql actually checks data, it's sufficient to know there is/are foreign keys in place my thinking being that it's impossible to add a child without the parent so it's safe just to know the fk exists